# Request is not going through the second time (It gives "undefined")

Tags: javascript, http, request

So I am trying to make my script pull out just the first article out of my database (it comes from the first page of google news) and display the description, title, etc but I also want to display a huge image from the original source of the article (if there is any-- but there is most likely one representing an article like always), so I am trying to make a second request to go inside the link of the info that I just pulled out of my database but the response is giving me "undefined". The first request works though.

Here is the code (first request is "var checkArticle =" and **the second one is at the bottom function called "function DiveIn() ", that second function is giving me undefined in the console.log** but I am doing it exactly like the first request so it should give data but its not)

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const request = require('request');
const request2 = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const fs = require('fs');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const ep = new AWS.Endpoint('*censored*.com');
const db = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({      // Dynamo database constructor
    "apiVersion": '2012-08-10',
    "region": 'us-west-1',
    "endpoint": ep,
    "accessKeyId": '*censored*',
    "secretAccessKey": '+v*censored*o6n'
});
require('events').EventEmitter.defaultMaxListeners = Infinity;
var url = "https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&gl=us&tbm=nws&authuser=0&q=u.s.&oq=u.s.&num=100&start=0";

//------  START MIDDLE WARE STUFF --------------  --------------------------------------------------------
router.use(function timeLog (req, res, next) {
  next();
});
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index');
});
module.exports = router; /*function(req,res,next) {
    res.render('index');
};*/
//------  END MIDDLE WARE STUFF --------------  -------------------------------------------------------- 





// ------------------------------UPDATE FRONT PAGE ARTICLE DATABASE------------------------------------ //
// this will be called after we collect our "subject" article"
var checkArticle = function (title, date, source, url, description) {

    this.title = title;
    this.date = date;
    this.url = url;
    this.source = source;
    this.description = description;
    // set it to date inserted to database
    date = new Date().toLocaleString();  
    let params = {
        TableName: "Articles"
    };

    db.scan(params, function(err,scannedData) {
        if (err) throw err;
            // scanData = target check
            // title + date + url + author = our subject article to check
            //asynchronously invoke a seperate function to display the current news right away, so there is no wait time

        console.log(`\n\n-------------------------------Subject Article:------------------------------- \n`);
        console.log("Title: " + title);
        console.log("Date: " + date);
        console.log("Source: " + source)
        console.log("description: " + description + '\n');
        console.log("URL: " + url);
            // pass this step to next function
        return Result(title, date, source, url, description, scannedData);
    });

    function Result(title, date, source, url, description,scannedData) {
        console.log("Peforming check...")
        let counter = 0;
            // peform check on all items. using 'counter' as the logic variable
        for (var i = 0; i < scannedData.Items.length; i++) {
            if (title === scannedData.Items[i].title) {
                counter++;
                console.log("We found a match. We are not performing anymore operations. \n -----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                return console.log("Stopped from inserting article to database.");
            }
        }
            // if a  match was found, it will execute this. Adds item to database
        if (counter === 0) {
            let params = {
                TableName: "Articles",
                Item: {
                    title: title,
                    date: date,
                    url: url,
                    source: source,
                    description: description
                }
            }
            db.put(params, function(err) {
                if (err) throw err;
                else { return; }
            });
            console.log("No matches found. Inserted article to 'Articles' database");
        }
    }
}

// This is for Front Page, news portion initiation
request(url, 'w+', function(err,data,body) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var $ = cheerio.load(body);
    //console.log($(".slp").prev().eq(2).text());   // title
    //console.log($(".slp").prev().children().eq(0).attr('href')); // url
    //console.log($(".slp").children().html());   // New York Times - 3 hours ago      //source - date
    //console.log($("div.st").eq(0).text());    // description
    let regExp = / - /;
    let urlSlice1 = $(".slp").prev().children().eq(0).attr('href').slice(7,Infinity);
    let urlSlice2 = urlSlice1.search(/&/);
    let urlSliced = urlSlice1.slice(0, urlSlice2);
    let hyphenBreakerForSource = $(".slp").children().html().search(regExp, "");        // gives the index # of found regExp
    //    got our meat of the burger.   //  /   /   //  //
    let source = $(".slp").children().html().slice(0,hyphenBreakerForSource);   //source 
    let date = $(".slp").children().html().slice(hyphenBreakerForSource + 3);       //date
    let url = urlSliced;
    url2 = urlSliced;
    let description = $("div.st").eq(0).text();
    let title = $(".slp").prev().eq(0).text();
    //          /// /   /   ////    /   /   /
    checkArticle(title, date, source, url, description);
});
// ------------------------------END FRONT PAGE ARTICLE OPERATION ------------------------------------- //

DiveIn();
function DiveIn() {
    let params = { TableName: "Articles" }
    db.scan(params, function(err,articleData) {
        let DiveInUrl = articleData.Items[0].url;
        request2(DiveInUrl, 'w+', function(err,body,DiveInData) {
            console.log(DiveinData);
        }) ;
    });
}
```

Comment: Any reason you did `const request2 = require('request');`? In `DiveIn`, what value has `err`?

Comment: Yeah I was trying to do request2 because I was trying to see if the original request was giving undefined because it was still being used in the function above for whatever reason. But its still giving undefined. I'll check err right now

Comment: The error says : "Error: Exceeded maxRedirects. Probably stuck in a redirect loop http://www.nytimes.com/2016/11/26/us/politics/us-cuba-relations-fidel-castro-donald-trump.html?_r=4"

Comment: Try setting the redirect treshold `require('request').defaults({maxRedirects:42})`

Comment: It works. Thank you :)